# What the hell is this keystroke for "Rotate left", in the Xcode iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode7

How do you execute this keystroke on a Mac?

[image]

on every Mac I have ever tried to use it, "Command-left arrow" seems to just cause confusion with the (absurd) "OS screen change" feature in OSX;

1. I have no clue how to change that key combo in the simulator?
2. On a typical Mac (2016) is there perhaps some way to disable the "OS screen change" filth in the finder, so that this works in the Xcode simulator??

For something like 5 years I have not been able to figure out how to spin the simulator using keystrokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Keyboard Shortcuts >> Mission Control and change the settings for "Move left a space" and "Move right a space" or disable them completely.

[image]

Select the red marked circle area to change keystroke. Instead of `command + arrow` key you can make it to `control + arrow` key. Simulator rotation with `command + arrow` should work now.

Comment: Thanks, enjoy that bounty!  :)